# Multiple mysql UPDATE with 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

is there a way to use multiples mysql UPDATE with only 1 query?

I need something like this but the code below seems to be not right.

```
$sql = "UPDATE car_models SET date='$date' WHERE ";

foreach ( $modelos as $mod ){
  $sql .= "(name='$mod->Label' AND car='$mod->model') AND ";
}

$sql = substr($sql, 0, -4); 
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

At the end I was expecting to have the $sql like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE car_models SET date='$date' WHERE (name='$mod->Label' AND car='$mod->model') AND (name='$mod->Label' AND car='$mod->model') AND (name='$mod->Label' AND car='$mod->model')";
```

Should it work? Or there is a different way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `$sql .= (name='$mod->Label' AND car='$mod->model') AND "; -` this line should not work, check if it is what you actually have.

Comment: *"Should it work?"*  No, there's a syntax error here, notice syntax highlighting? There's a missing quote.

Comment: I hope that wasn't a bad paste.

Comment: you should search about procedures to do it professionally

Comment: @svgrafov  was missing a quote in this line.  This question was not a copy and past so was a typo while I was typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `OR` instead of `AND` at the end of the string:

```
$sql .= "(name='$mod->Label' AND car='$mod->model') OR ";
```

And pay close attention to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `UPDATE car_models SET date='$date' WHERE name IN $array_of_car_name AND car IN $array_of_car_model`